# Shorten an SQL request

Tags: sql

I cannot find out how to do it in another way.

It works, but it is not perfect ( in my opinion ) or is there a better way to solve this problem?

```
SELECT TOP 1 a.DB, a.Com, a.User, a.Port 
FROM tab_1 a 
WHERE a.DB + a.Com NOT IN (SELECT b.DB + b.Com 
                           FROM tb_2 b) 
ORDER BY ID
```

Is there any way to shorten this SQL statement or make it more clear?

Comment: This code is potentially going to be very slow on large tables.

Comment: why are using Top 1. Why are you adding fields together. Making a wild guess you need something like this: `SELECT TOP 1 a.DB, a.Com, a.User, a.Port 
FROM tab_1 a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM tb_2 b WHERE a.DB = b.DB AND a.Com = b.Com) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT TOP 1 a.DB, a.Com, a.User, a.Port 
FROM tab_1 a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tab_2 b
ON b.com = a.com
AND b.DB = a.DB
WHERE b.DB IS NULL
AND b.Com IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was it I was looking for, but I have to admit I always have problems with the LEFT OUTER JOINS and those things. INNER JOIN is easy to understand, but using a LEFT OUTER JOIN is always hard for me to use. Thank you very much!